# changing images within a 'flash embedded image'

Tags: javascript

We are a little stuck however on the following embedded flash image:

```
[kml_flashembed movie="http://www.griffintaxfree.com/images/logos/stacklogos.swf" height="250" width="500" /]
```

I need to know how to open up this, change the images within it, and then re-post it to our web page.

It was created by someone who no-longer handles our site.

Answer (score 0):

## Downloading the file...

**If you can navigate directly to the URL** *(your case)*:

Use the `Save Page As...` feature, *typically under File, or Page Settings in most browsers*

**If it is embedded within a page:**

You can usually navigate to the file itself, by looking at the available items on the page, such as using the following in Firefox:

```
Tools => Page Info => Media => Find the flash file => Save As...
```

or by scouring through the source and finding a link to the file itself and saving it.

## Editing the file...

The editing process however, can be much more difficult, especially if you don't have anyone with experience working with Flash. You will need a Flash Decompiler to make the file editable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Flash Decompiler. Once the program is compiled to SWF it is very difficult to extract what's inside.

If you can get the program to display the image it's probably easier to take a screenshot.